# Directory too big for git

Tags: git, version-control

I have a project with two directories I would like to version-control. Next to these directories are temporary build files. Is there any chance to setup gitignore properly? It seems git still complains about the project size

Here is my directory:

```
./
 +--- source1 (1000 files)
 |   +---headers
 |   +---sources
 |   +---temp_project_files (1000 files don't belong to git)
 |
 +--- source2 (1000 files)
 |   +---headers
 |   +---sources
 |   +---temp_project_files (1000 files don't belong to git)
 |
 +--- temp_build (80.000) files
 |
 |
 +--- .gitignore
```

My gitignore file contains this:

```
!/source1/**/*.cpp
!/source1/**/*.h
!/source2/**/*.cpp
!/source2/**/*.h
```

So I filter out everything except for *.cpp and *.h files, still git complains by telling me:

```
> The git repository at /path/to/dir/ has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled.
```

Reason for that is, that git seems to check in all files from gitignore as `untracked`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Git has no hardcoded limit on the number of files. This message about "too many active changes" must come from some other software.

Comment: No, Git will complain if you have a ton of changes that you are adding all at once. It's not about the number of files, but the number of changes pending commit.

Comment: @OrdoFlammae: I've searched the Git source for the message; it's not in there. I tried reproducing the problem by creating 100,000 files; that worked fine too.

Comment: I haven't actually gotten this myself. It might be associated with Visual Studio, all the feedback I saw on getting this error message was on Visual Studio and related GitHub pages. Either that, or possibly it's Windows (although I doubt that). Either way, if you searched in the Git source, you're probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directories and files are automatically set as tracked if not dealt with in the `.gitignore` file. Therefore, you need to specifically add the folders you want to ignore, not the ones you do not want to ignore. You would add the ones you would not want to ignore if they're in a directory you're already ignoring. Therefore, you probably want this in your `.gitignore` file.

```
temp_build/
source1/temp_project_files/
source2/temp_project_files/
```

If you add a folder to `.gitignore`, it will automatically ignore all the files and folders inside that folder.

Also, the error you are getting is probably not related to the size of the directory, but instead, related to you making all the changes at once.

Note: If you really really want to do things the way you are, stick a * up at the top of your `.gitignore`, that'll ignore all files and folders by default.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. The problem was indeed that the directories were not properly captured and therefore were marked to get committed

Answer (score 2):

Why not to ignore the entire directories, just two entries needed in `.gitignore`

```
temp_project_files/
temp_build/
```

Comment: I inverted my gitignore loci and it makes more sense that way, indeed!